# How to connect our push button to ZYNQ-based board's GPIO?

Tags: fpga, gpio, zynq, parallella

I want to add external push button to Parallella's GPIO pins.
Is it correct to connect push button just like the users did for Raspberry pi boards? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdlXv.jpg)

if it's working, what resistor should I use? and if it's not correct, what schematic should I follow to connect push-button to one of the GPIOs?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a quick look at the Parallella schematic. It is 17 pages with rather a lot of connections so I can't do a full analysis in a few minutes. (I would also need to work through the datasheet)

You must check which voltage your I/O pin is operating at. If it is 3V3 you can use the schematic as-is. If it is a different voltage you have to replace the 3V3
with whatever the I/O voltage is. For the rest the principle is OK: Pull the port low with a resistor and use a push button to the selected voltage to make it active high.

If you don't know which voltage to use set the pin in output mode and output a 'high' Then measure which voltage appears.

Note that in general it is safer way to use a resistor (e.g. 50KOhm) to tie the pin to the I/O voltage. Then use a push button to pull the pin low. If you make a mistake, the pin is more likely to survive as the resistor limits the current.